# MongoDB: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

So I have this application that continuously pushes data to my database.
It has been working fine for over a year now. But in the past few days I keep getting this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/veristats_backend-2.0.0_0-py2.7.egg/drivertest/utils.py", line 141, in lock
    db.find_one_and_update(key, {'$set': {'locked': False}})
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2454, in find_one_and_update
    sort, upsert, return_document, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2222, in __find_and_modify
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 868, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
    address))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: l-veristats-01:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

My applications runs for a minute or so and then it crashes like this.

**EDIT**
When this happens i get:

```
# systemctl status mongodb
Unit mongodb.service could not be found.
```

I also see in the log this line:

```
019-08-07T09:15:14.475+0300 I COMMAND  [conn137619] warning: log line attempted (2200kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ...
```

Could it be that this is what causes the mongod service to stop?

**EDIT2**
I also see that the OOM killer is what actually killing the service:

```
# grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
Aug  5 22:33:12 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 18849 (mongod) total-vm:4871984kB, anon-rss:2287364kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  5 22:33:12 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 18862 (mongod) total-vm:4871984kB, anon-rss:2313000kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  5 22:33:12 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 18896 (mongod) total-vm:4871984kB, anon-rss:2312572kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  5 22:33:12 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 19084 (mongod) total-vm:4871984kB, anon-rss:2312600kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 09:12:29 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 1586 (mongod) total-vm:4052764kB, anon-rss:1544224kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 09:31:13 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 31266 (mongod) total-vm:3517068kB, anon-rss:1589668kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 09:31:13 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 31277 (mongod) total-vm:3517068kB, anon-rss:1597916kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 09:34:04 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 31613 (veristats_drive) total-vm:3179060kB, anon-rss:1397368kB, file-rss:132kB, shmem-rss:8kB
Aug  6 09:46:13 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 2781 (mongod) total-vm:3265204kB, anon-rss:676164kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 11:14:45 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 1616 (mongod) total-vm:3566624kB, anon-rss:1608752kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 11:50:55 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 2004 (mongod) total-vm:3220196kB, anon-rss:433892kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 13:31:18 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 6914 (mongod) total-vm:2952284kB, anon-rss:509968kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 13:39:21 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 7894 (veristats_drive) total-vm:2543372kB, anon-rss:1404448kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 13:39:33 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 7895 (veristats_drive) total-vm:2550052kB, anon-rss:1277732kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 13:39:43 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 7899 (veristats_drive) total-vm:2853180kB, anon-rss:1854872kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 13:41:15 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 7579 (mongod) total-vm:3361372kB, anon-rss:713976kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 15:31:59 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 5304 (veristats_drive) total-vm:2645104kB, anon-rss:1579280kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 15:32:43 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 5309 (veristats_drive) total-vm:4463076kB, anon-rss:2628364kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 15:36:04 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 1656 (mongod) total-vm:3106644kB, anon-rss:996140kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 15:36:20 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 5682 (veristats_drive) total-vm:2127152kB, anon-rss:1161560kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  6 17:36:59 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 1911 (mongod) total-vm:3687888kB, anon-rss:907436kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  7 09:15:17 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 9349 (mongod) total-vm:4044552kB, anon-rss:1413928kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  7 09:30:55 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 17966 (mongod) total-vm:3254812kB, anon-rss:1058928kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug  7 09:35:15 l-veristats-01 kernel: Killed process 18993 (mongod) total-vm:2405540kB, anon-rss:361824kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Comment: what is mongodb status then? systemctl status mongodb or simillar. Try to add some mongodb logs. The problem can be lack of disk space or whatever

Comment: See edit please.

Comment: To be honest it looks like the problem not in pymongo, but in VM resources. I suppose the problem is in lack of memory(because of Linux OOM killer). is there anything useful in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log? not warnings but an error?

Comment: Also the lack of memory can happen when you do read queries without DB indexes properly configured. In this case try to add some.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever change mongo version? Try to update your pymongo.